# MySQL: select query on two databases

Tags: mysql, magento

I'm trying to get data from two databases (they are on the same server). What I want is get data from Database 2 by a value of Database 1. I'm struggling with the JOIN. I want to match on ean (d.value), cause this one does exist in the second database too.

```
SELECT 
    a.sku AS sku, 
    c.value AS name, 
    d.value AS ean,
    e.value AS price,
    f.n_factuurprijs AS tech_price
FROM 
    catalog_product_entity a, 
    catalog_product_entity_int b, 
    catalog_product_entity_varchar c, 
    catalog_product_entity_varchar d,
    catalog_product_entity_decimal e
JOIN
    product_stock_price.techdata_products f ON f.ean = ean
WHERE 
    a.entity_id = b.entity_id
    AND a.entity_id = c.entity_id
    AND a.entity_id = d.entity_id
    AND a.entity_id = e.entity_id
    AND d.attribute_id = f.ean
    AND b.attribute_id = 96
    AND b.value = 1
    AND c.attribute_id = 71
    AND d.attribute_id = 152
    AND e.attribute_id = 75 
GROUP BY a.entity_id
```

As you can see, I am quite new with MySQL. So any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would specify the database by using the syntax databasename.tablename
e.g.

```
SELECT 
    db1.user_table.id, 
    db2.user_table.id
FROM 
   db1.user_table
       INNER JOIN db2.user_table 
           ON db1.user_table.id = db2.user_table.id
```